# SQL Like clause returning same value on different items

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have this block of code below which uses the like clause on a comboBox and passes the relevant item number from the database to a textbox. It works but there is one issue. I type in a value and as you can see below it brings up the two as expected:

[image]

My issue is that when selecting either of the options displayed it brings u the same item number in the textBox it is being passed to. As shown in the two screenshots below:

[image]

Second Screen with different item with same item number:

[image]

They don't have the same item numbers in the database. Where am I going wrong? The code is below:

```
private void suggestComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            string connectionString = "Data Source=bid;Initial Catalog=BI_ST;Integrated Security=True";
            string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.IV00 WHERE ITEMDESC LIKE '%" + suggestComboBox2.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''") + "%'; ";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string cari_code = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("ITEMNMBR"));
                textBox2.Text = cari_code;
                string intFromSmallInt = Convert.ToString(dr.GetInt16(dr.GetOrdinal("ITEMTYPE")));
                textBox12.Text = intFromSmallInt;

                //con.Close();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }


        //      ? Color.Black : Color.Red;
        //    }
    }
}
```

See same query from SQL Server which proves the item numbers are unique:
[image]

Comment: Does your database contain any `pickles%'; DROP TABLE dbo.IV00; --` ?

Comment: Are you sure that the output of your sql query returns unique item number? Please post database output by running the query directly into SSMS

Comment: You are overwriting the textbox values in each iteration of `Read()`. You will always get the last returned row.

Comment: on another note, this is the perfect time to use [The Debugger](https://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging)

Comment: @Crowcoder is there a work around I can as to eliminate this problem?

Comment: @Rex I added it

Comment: @AdamNewman a text box is not the control you want to use if you have multiple values. I don't know the point of your search but you should probably populate a grid or something with the results.

Comment: @SamIam am not sure I understand what you are asking

Comment: looks like itemdesc is ntext type to compare you need a cast, try replacing ITEMDESC in your sql query with: CAST(ITEMDESC AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

Comment: @AdamNewman If what you're selecting is an item, you should query only one item when selecting, based on the itemNumber.  You only need to use the `like` query for when you type the filter

Comment: @Crowcoder it searches a comboBox for a value of items and then writes it to a database. This is the better way. The grid would not achieve what I want it to

Comment: @AdamNewman  First make sure you're connecting to a Database that you don't mind ruining, and then try typing what I wrote into your search box and see what happens.

Comment: You desperately need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @AdamNewman You have more of a design problem than a code problem. Typically a search presents a list to a user who then chooses one of the results to then perform a task with.

Comment: @SamIam I see your point without taking that risk

Comment: @Crowcoder technically that is what is happening here. It does a search of the drop down list and they select the option to be written to wherever.

Comment: @Crowcoder any suggestions to prevent it being overwritten?

Comment: @AdamNewman I Think I may understand now and Sam I Am told you the solution already. Query where the id equals something, not the description is LIKE something so you get only one row.

Comment: Show the query you fill your combo box with. You should be setting the value of the combo box with the unique identifier of the item. ex. `ItemID`. Set the combo box text with the description. Then in `suggestComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged_1` use the `ItemID` in your query to fill the text box.

Answer (score 0):

When your selected index changes, you are selecting the same set from the database and looping through ALL the results:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    string cari_code = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("ITEMNMBR"));
    textBox2.Text = cari_code;
    string intFromSmallInt = 
    Convert.ToString(dr.GetInt16(dr.GetOrdinal("ITEMTYPE")));
    textBox12.Text = intFromSmallInt;

    //con.Close();

}
```

This causes the last `Read()` to be what gets used. From your picture, it's number 2: `0160-12011`.

What you need to do is modify your program such that the query uses the ID behind the description (`itemnmbr`) to fetch you only the result you need.

Comment: But that would move away from what I am trying to do. Which is to populate my textBox with the item numbers based on the item description that are in the adjacent column in my database.

Comment: @AdamNewman: What you need to understand is that the description is just a search aid. As you type, you are populating the dropdown with possible matches. You figured out that part. Now, when someone makes a selection from the list, they are selecting a particular ITEM (not a description). When the selected index changes, you have narrowed the search to a single item so at that point, you should use the itemnmbr column instead and issue a query for just that record.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so people have highlighted a lot of problems with your code. Besides that, the reason why your code is doing as expected is because every time the index changes on the combo box you are writing the last result in the database to the textbox.

Maybe checking if the description matches the combo box selection, that could fix your issue

```
 while (dr.Read())
 {
 string cari_code = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("ITEMNMBR"));
 string intFromSmallInt = Convert.ToString(dr.GetInt16(dr.GetOrdinal("ITEMTYPE")));
 var desc = Convert.ToString(dr.GetOrdinal("itemdesc"));
 if(suggestComboBox2.Text.Equals(desc)){
 textBox12.Text = intFromSmallInt;
   textBox2.Text = cari_code;
 }
 //con.Close();
}
```

Comment: While matching the description "could" fix the issue, it is still prone to errors. In general, it's not a good idea to match on descriptions. That's what IDs are for. Then there is the unnecessary loading of data where only one record is needed.

Comment: @Juan I agree, it is completely bad practice but I'm simply trying to show him where he went wrong and giving him a simple solution which he can use to understand.

Comment: thanks for input but now it doesn't return the item number to the textBox at all@JoshuaDuxbury

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is this. I'm making assumptions about the data type of `ITEMNMBR` and I'm not null checking anything, but this code will properly dispose your resources, prevent SQL injection, and select only the data for the item selected in the combo:

```
private void suggestComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=bid;Initial Catalog=BI_ST;Integrated Security=True";
        string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.IV00 WHERE ITEMNMBR = @itemnmbr;";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = query;                
                var parItemNmbr = cmd.Parameters.Add("@itemnmbr", SqlDbType.Int);
                parItemNmbr.Value = suggestComboBox2.SelectedValue;
                con.Open();

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dr.Read();

                string cari_code = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("ITEMNMBR"));
                textBox2.Text = cari_code;

                string intFromSmallInt = Convert.ToString(dr.GetInt16(dr.GetOrdinal("ITEMTYPE")));
                textBox12.Text = intFromSmallInt;
            }       
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate how you addressed the many flaws in my code but could you help me with the error when it says: `The parameterized query '(@itemnmbr int)SELECT * FROM dbo.IV00 WHERE ITEMNMBR = @itemnmbr' expects the parameter '@itemnmbr', which was not supplied`

Comment: Maybe the `SelectedValue` of the combobox is null. What is in the combo and what are set for `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`? If it contains only a set of strings then you will have to modify its data source to include the `ITEMNMBR`.

Comment: It contains nothing currently. The comboBox is being filled by a function that is populating item descriptions from my database

Comment: So, strings then. You need to populate it with objects that have a property for the descriptions and one for the item number if you want to do it as I have described. The combobox `DisplayMember` will be the object's description property and the `ValueMember` will be it's item number property. Working with comboboxes in this was is very well documented on the interwebs.